# How to allow SQL to be more flexible about what is imputed 'RR-MM-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM' creates [22008][1855] ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to input the date in a few different ways.

1. `to_timestamp('2015-10-06 0:00:00.0 AM', 'RR-MM-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM')`

and

2. `to_timestamp('2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 AM', 'RR-MM-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM')`

**Errors for both**

1. `ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12`
2. `[22008][1855] ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required`

What I am trying to achieve is the ability to use `2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 AM` or `2015-10-06 0:00:00.0 AM` without it giving me an error about the constraints here `'RR-MM-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM'`.

Comment: `RR` is the year without century, try `YYYY` instead.

Comment: Check [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock): *Each period consists of 12 hours numbered: 12 (acting as zero), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11.* - 0 is not allowed.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I wrote a script that extracted the data and I am not taking the same data and putting it back in. When I added `HH24` that resulted in `ORA-01818: 'HH24' precludes use of meridian indicator`

Comment: That meas you must not use `AM` or `PM` - you cannot use 12 and 24 hours format at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

A 12-hour clock does not have a 0th hour.

If you want to support a 0th hour as an alias for the 12th hour then you can write a custom function to replace the 0 with 12:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3cb5e/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parse_timestamp(
  in_string VARCHAR2
) RETURN TIMESTAMP
IS
  p_string    VARCHAR2(30) := in_string;
  c_fix_hours CHAR(61) := '^(\d{1,4}-\d\d?-\d\d? )00?(:[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d(\.\d+)? [AP]M)$';
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE( p_string, c_fix_hours, 'i' ) THEN
    p_string := REGEXP_REPLACE( p_string, c_fix_hours, '\112\2', 1, 1, 'i' );
  END IF;
  RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP( p_string, 'RR-MM-DD HH12.MI.SSXFF AM' );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT parse_timestamp(
         '2015-10-06 0:00:00.0 AM'
       ),
       parse_timestamp(
         '2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 AM'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3cb5e/4/0)**:

```
| PARSE_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-060:00:00.0AM') | PARSE_TIMESTAMP('2115-10-0601:00:00.0AM') |
|------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
|                    2015-10-06 00:00:00.0 |                     2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 |
```

**Update** use a `CASE` statement:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/489)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH test_data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '2015-10-06 0:00:00.0 AM'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 AM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '5-9-7 00:59:59.234 PM'    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
         CASE
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( value, '^(\d{1,4}-\d\d?-\d\d? )00?(:[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d(\.\d+)? [AP]M)$', 'i' )
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '^(\d{1,4}-\d\d?-\d\d? )00?(:[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d(\.\d+)? [AP]M)$', '\112\2', 1, 1, 'i' ) 
         ELSE value
         END,
         'RR-MM-DD HH12.MI.SSXFF AM'
       ) AS datetime
FROM   test_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/489/0)**:

```
|                DATETIME |
|-------------------------|
|   2015-10-06 00:00:00.0 |
|   2115-10-06 01:00:00.0 |
| 2005-09-07 12:59:59.234 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response but I cannot change anything the database. It would go against what I am testing. What I need to figure out is for it to let me to use `24H` time format. Advice?

Comment: @noname_dev Use a `CASE` statement.